# Why we need "request" object when return render()?

Tags: django

Sorry if this is too basic. I'm new to the django framework.

And this comes to my mind when return using render()

```
    render(request,templates,context)
```

templates is in the folder; context is for the template and is already got .

So my question is what's the request object doing here? Aren't the template and context enough to return a response? Thanks.

Comment: django is open source! All the code is available online, `render` is available at: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/shortcuts.py#L25

Answer (score 0):

`render` requireds `request` because it forces `RequestContext`, which requires `request`

This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), and can be seen in the code as well.

Django documentation is excellent, and should be an initial source for any questions

Comment: Thanks. I dive into the document and find out looks like The TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting which is context processors requires a request object. But why this setting requires it???